# Passing different content to template parts

Tags: php

I have created a split screen template which I want to use accross various pages. I want the content to be different on both sides in all of these templates. How do I pass in different content to each side of these template parts? Or is there another way?

I was considering adding the split screen for each page, but that isn't very DRY. My split screen template HTML is below:

```
<section id="content">
    <section class="left-split">
        <div class="left-split-content">

            // left side content here

        </div><!-- left split content -->
    </section><!-- left split -->

    <section class="right-split" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="70">
        <div class="right-split-content clearfix">

            // right side content here

        </div><!-- content -->
    </section><!-- right split content -->

</section><!-- content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Simply call the template part in each place.

```
<?php get_template_part('content','left'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php get_template_part('content','right'); ?>
```

You would then create `content-left.php` and `content-right.php` templates.

**2.** A different approach would be to call `do_action` there instead. eg.

```
<?php do_action('template_content_left'); ?>
```

This could give you an extra level of control over the content template used. 
eg. in your functions.php you could use something like:

```
if (is_page('special')) {add_action('template_content_left','template_special_content_left');} 
else {add_action('template_content_left','template_content_left');}  

function template_special_content_left() {get_template_part('special-content','left');}
function template_content_left() {get_template_part('content','left');}
```

This may suit you better if you need to get the content from different places depending on the current page conditions.

**EDIT** custom field example, closer to needs described...

```
if (is_page('about-us')) {
    add_action('template_content_left','template_menu_output');
    add_action('template_content_right','template_content_output');
} 
elseif (is_page('services')) {
    add_action('template_content_left','template_services_field_left');
    add_action('template_content_right','template_services_field_right');
}

function template_menu_output() {echo "CUSTOM MENU";}
function template_content_output() {the_content();}

function template_services_field_Left() {
    global $post; echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'fieldkey1',true);
}
function template_services_field_right() {
    global $post; echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'fieldkey2',true);
}
```

Just replace with ACF functions for outputting the desired fields.

Comment: Thank you! I think that's close to an answer. But what I mean is for instance on my 'about us' there will be a menu on the left and content on the right. But on my 'services' there will be content on both sides. So how can I change the content which will be added in that space according to which page I am on. I will be using ACF if that makes any difference.

Comment: You probably want to go for using the `do_action` method then, because you can hook any funciton to that action conditionally, including the output of a custom field.